# Drupal Commons site has no style after install - missin js and css files at all

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, drupal-6, firebug

the **very last / newest update**

on a quick step i did the **toogle the css-aggregation** - and switched it to off: see the results of this action on the  site: http://campus-24.com/

i had toggled the css-aggregation to off - in the performance-section:

see the first results: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/842/viewactivitylogstreamdi.jpg/
well i have to do more...

http://commons.acquia.com/discussion/no-theme-new-install

http://commons.acquia.com/discussion/no-theme-new-install#comment-15346

> I also had the same problem and it was solved by disabling CSS
>   Optimizaition. checked all my CSS under
>   /profiles/drupalcommons/themes, and all are UTF-8. Hi give this a try,
>   you might find an answer http://drupal.org/node/445462 It seems to
>   indicate I found the solution. You just have to convert all your css
>   files in unix/utf8 and it's done.  Hope it helps

[end of the very very latest input to this topic]

hello dear users - good day all! Besides some ideas from drupalers to upload a new theme [since the old basic one could have some issues shipped with i have found an overview where settings and configurations could be made.

Well now i found out how to see some overiews - and made a big step ahead - now i ve landed in the View activity_log_stream, displaying items of type Activity Log: [see the image:](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/40/viewactivitylogstreamdi.jpg/)  here i can change alot!  well but i guess that i have to figure out how...!?

This view can be generated with this setup - site: http://campus-24.com/?q=admin/build/views/edit/activity_log_stream#views-tab-page_2 Now i am happy to see some overview on a site where i can make some adjustments and configurations: see Home » Administer » Site building » Views:  Here i seem to be able to Edit view activity_log_stream

http://campus-24.com/?q=admin/build/views/edit/activity_log_stream
**View activity_log_stream,** displaying items of type Activity Log.

But i must say that i need some recomondations to figure out how to  get some styles on to the page. Do you have some recommodations i love to hear from you  many many greetings

btw: you can have the admin login 
just let me know just contact me...

I tried to export the setting-data: **Note:** The file could not be created.

see http://campus-24.com/?q=admin/build/views/export/activity_log_stream

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'activity_log_stream';
$view->description = 'Displays activity streams.';
$view->tag = '';
$view->view_php = '';
$view->base_table = 'activity_log_messages';
$view->is_cacheable = FALSE;
$view->api_version = 2;
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Defaults', 'default');
$handler->override_option('fields', array(
  'message' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'message',
    'table' => 'activity_log_messages',
    'field' => 'message',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('sorts', array(
  'last_updated' => array(
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'granularity' => 'second',
    'id' => 'last_updated',
    'table' => 'activity_log_messages',
    'field' => 'last_updated',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('arguments', array(
  'stream_owner_type' => array(
    'default_action' => 'ignore',
    'style_plugin' => 'default_summary',
    'style_options' => array(),
    'wildcard' => 'all',
    'wildcard_substitution' => 'All',
    'title' => '',
    'breadcrumb' => '',
    'default_argument_type' => 'activity_log_default_stream_owner_type',
    'default_argument' => '',
    'validate_type' => 'activity_log_validate_stream_owner_type',
    'validate_fail' => 'not found',
    'glossary' => 0,
    'limit' => '0',
    'case' => 'none',
    'path_case' => 'none',
    'transform_dash' => 0,
    'id' => 'stream_owner_type',
    'table' => 'activity_log_messages',
    'field' => 'stream_owner_type',
    'validate_user_argument_type' => 'uid',
    'validate_user_roles' => array(
      '2' => 0,
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'default_options_div_prefix' => '',
    'default_argument_fixed' => '',
    'default_argument_user' => 0,
    'default_argument_activity_log_stream_owner_type' => 'user',
    'default_argument_php' => '',
    'validate_argument_node_type' => array(
      'page' => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_node_access' => 0,
    'validate_argument_nid_type' => 'nid',
    'validate_argument_vocabulary' => array(
      '1' => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_type' => 'tid',
    'validate_argument_transform' => 0,
    'validate_user_restrict_roles' => 0,
    'validate_argument_php' => '',
  ),
  'stream_owner_id' => array(
    'default_action' => 'ignore',
    'style_plugin' => 'default_summary',
    'style_options' => array(),
    'wildcard' => 'all',
    'wildcard_substitution' => 'All',
    'title' => '',
    'breadcrumb' => '',
    'default_argument_type' => 'current_user',
    'default_argument' => '',
    'validate_type' => 'none',
    'validate_fail' => 'not found',
    'break_phrase' => 0,
    'not' => 0,
    'include' => array(
      'og' => 0,
      'ur' => 0,
    ),
    'id' => 'stream_owner_id',
    'table' => 'activity_log_messages',
    'field' => 'stream_owner_id',
    'validate_user_argument_type' => 'uid',
    'validate_user_roles' => array(
      '2' => 0,
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'default_options_div_prefix' => '',
    'default_argument_fixed' => '',
    'default_argument_user' => 0,
    'default_argument_activity_log_stream_owner_type' => 'user',
    'default_argument_php' => '',
    'validate_argument_node_type' => array(
      'page' => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_node_access' => 0,
    'validate_argument_nid_type' => 'nid',
    'validate_argument_vocabulary' => array(
      '1' => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_type' => 'tid',
    'validate_argument_transform' => 0,
    'validate_user_restrict_roles' => 0,
    'validate_argument_php' => '',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('filters', array(
  'display_type' => array(
    'operator' => '=',
    'value' => 'web',
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'display_type',
    'table' => 'activity_log_templates',
    'field' => 'display_type',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('access', array(
  'type' => 'perm',
  'perm' => 'view all activity messages',
));
$handler->override_option('cache', array(
  'type' => 'none',
));
$handler->override_option('empty', 'There are no visible status updates.');
$handler->override_option('empty_format', '1');
$handler->override_option('use_ajax', TRUE);
$handler->override_option('items_per_page', 20);
$handler->override_option('use_pager', '1');
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page_1');
$handler->override_option('path', 'activities');
$handler->override_option('menu', array(
  'type' => 'normal',
  'title' => 'Activity stream',
  'description' => 'Displays activity streams.',
  'weight' => '0',
  'name' => 'navigation',
));
$handler->override_option('tab_options', array(
  'type' => 'none',
  'title' => '',
  'description' => '',
  'weight' => 0,
  'name' => 'navigation',
));
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page_2');
$handler->override_option('path', '');
$handler->override_option('menu', array(
  'type' => 'none',
  'title' => '',
  'description' => '',
  'weight' => 0,
  'name' => 'navigation',
));
$handler->override_option('tab_options', array(
  'type' => 'none',
  'title' => '',
  'description' => '',
  'weight' => 0,
  'name' => 'navigation',
));
```

If you want to have look at the admin area  - just lemme know!

**by the way** - i noticed that the  following tables were not being created in the new installation..

```
    og_access_post 
    og_notifications 
    content_group 
    content_group_fields 
    facebook_status_tags 
    fbss_comments
```

for whatever reason - i do not know..

on a first sight i tink that the following two tables might be of some more specific interest: what do you think!?

```
content_group 
content_group_fields
```

well at the moment i still try to find out what is missing - which issues caused the serious lack of style.
generally spoken: as for being confronted with the **site still remaining the same** - after the hard core changes[of last night due to my server-admin while chhanging the chown and chmod of the whole site], i am musing about all the tiny things and changes i did last week: i will try to go through all tiny changes i made

i will check all the **site-administration-adjustments** tonight: i had some corrections and tests done last week accordingly some hints: "This is due that by install in the performance administrative section ( admin/settings/performance ) you have on Bandwidth optimizations the option "OPTIMIZE CSS FILES" and "OPTIMIZE JAVASCRIPT FILES" enabled. This settings are normally very usefully for production(live) sites-  i did this for testing and customize the Drupal Commons install cuz i thougth that it's better to disable as to have CSS and JS development support with tools like "Firebug" using Firefox."

What **has been done during the last 24 hours:** accordingly to all the suggested and adviced changes that are made by

```
Bon Espresso
Siwei Shen 
Shaun Dychko
clive
```

My Server-admin made some changes for /home/vhost/WWW/campus-24.com/ 
For all files/folders the **permission-/ownership-settings** were set to

```
owner vhost:www
664 for files  and  2775 for the folders)
```

also  the following corrctions / adjustments  were made:

```
       php_admin_value open_basedir
"/home/vhost/WWW/campus-24.com/:/usr/local/httpd/icons/"
       php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
       php_flag session.auto_start               off
       php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
       php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
       php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
       php_admin_value memory_limit    128M
       php_admin_value max_input_time  360
       php_admin_value post_max_size   16M
       php_admin_flag safe_mode_gid off
       php_admin_flag safe_mode off
```

but the site does not look different at the moment. All is still stylefree:
[note: due to some advices from last week i have set in admin settings the css & js settings to a special mode to a **somewhat called off-mode**]. Guess that i can do some corrections here too]

Well, no changes in the look & feel appeared. Guess that this is just not surprising since the correct permission were missing during the installation - so i guess that i have to do a installation with the correct permissions - and ownership then all will go all right!?

**end of update**

here the **orginal posting** with all the description and ideas

Drupal Commons site has no style after install: it looks like www.campus-24.com

**update:** thanks to Siwei Shen that asks below for the permission on the specified paths - eg as the "www-data" user. Well i  guess that i am not able to read the css-folder. 
  No - i am not since all of the below mentined **folders are owned by the wwwrun-user**

We have the following ones in

```
/home/vhost/WWW/campus-24.com/sites/default/files/js
/home/vhost/WWW/campus-24.com/sites/default/files/css
/home/vhost/WWW/campus-24.com/sites/default/files/imagecache
/home/vhost/WWW/campus-24.com/sites/default/files/ctools
/home/vhost/WWW/campus-24.com/sites/default/files/pictures
```

But the folders contain files - that are owned by the vhost-user. 
**But wait:** i guess that i have copied the files into the folders afterwards (sorry sorry i cannot remember this exact story any more) i tried everything i coud do. Guessing that i also did a try to copy the files into the  folder.
But the most interesting thing to me is - that the **folders are owned by the wwwrun-user.** What do you think!?

Besides the above mentined folders the two **files are owned by the wwwrun-user**

- default-user.png
- default-group.png

During the install i noticed warnings about - too many files open.

i heard about the "css_1acaad3d96ebad99fc9b6ef9d4ee4.css" file: This is called an automatic generated file that compress all CSS styles used as to improve speed and help not overloading rendering. What if this file is missin in my folder - does my site than have (!!!) to look like the above mentined site?

**Note** the original htaccess was changed by my server-admin. But i guess that i (
and that means the site-admin [my friend] miss (and have forgotten a important option] see the htacess that  we use actually - it is a hacked one: see it here
pastebin.de/22149

see the Link http://campus-24.com/?q=stream

No picture, no css. Is there any right or permission problem ?

see the error reporting
http://campus-24.com/?q=admin/settings/error-reporting

**Error reporting**

```
The configuration options have been saved.

    warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array in /home/vhost/WWW/campus-24.com/modules/system/system.module on line 1020.
    warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/vhost/WWW/campus-24.com/includes/theme.inc on line 1832.
    warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/vhost/WWW/campus-24.com/includes/theme.inc on line 1832.
```

see much much more error-reporting:

**see much much more error-logs:** http://pastebin.de/22378

on the site http://campus-24.com/?q=admin/help/dblog - i have the dblog-log-info
What is the output of "cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr"?

see here the dblog log which is simply a list of recorded events containing usage data, performance data, errors, warnings and operational information.

```
Type    php
Date    Monday, 16 January, 2012 - 21:47
User    martin
Location    http://campus-24.com/?q=admin/reports
Referrer    http://campus-24.com/?q=stream
Message array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/vhost/WWW/campus-24.com/includes/theme.inc on line 1832.
Severity    error
Hostname    188.99.183.60


Type    php
Date    Monday, 16 January, 2012 - 21:47
User    martin
Location    http://campus-24.com/?q=admin/reports
Referrer    http://campus-24.com/?q=stream
Message array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/vhost/WWW/campus-24.com/includes/theme.inc on line 1832.
Severity    error
Hostname    188.99.183.60
Operations  


Type    php
Date    Monday, 16 January, 2012 - 21:47
User    martin
Location    http://campus-24.com/?q=admin/reports
Referrer    http://campus-24.com/?q=stream
Message array_map() [<a href='function.array-map'>function.array-map</a>]: Argument #2 should be an array in /home/vhost/WWW/campus-24.com/modules/system/system.module on line 1020.
Severity    error
Hostname    188.99.183.60
Operations

Type    php
Date    Monday, 16 January, 2012 - 21:47
User    martin
Location    http://campus-24.com/?q=stream
Referrer    
Message Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/vhost/WWW/campus-24.com/includes/theme.inc on line 1832.
Severity    error
Hostname    188.99.183.60
Operations
```

guess that some tiny things are missing - as said above: i come back and report all the findings.

Comment: I'm facing with this problem and currently not to use OPTIMIZE feature.

Comment: hello dear Bon Espresso. Great to hear from you! Do you have the same issue? I am very very happy about this. Since i thought that i am the only one that is facing this problem. Well - what to do now!? You advice me not (!!!!) to use the OPTIMIZE-feature!? Well - one questin left. Where to adjust this... Where is the option... in the settings-file that i edit manually?! Before installation begins!?

Comment: There are options on Drupal's setting (of course, after installation and you have administrative permission). Visit [Drupal Performance setting](http://yourdomain.com/#overlay=admin/config/development/performance) and uncheck two options "Aggregate and compress CSS files." and "Aggregate JavaScript files." I'm going to find the root cause and I will tell you if I found somethings wrong.

Comment: hello bon Espresso great to hear from you! 

Well see the drupal commons running here: 

http://taxigourmet.net/ and http://boysday.org  and http://campus-24.com/?q=user/1
i try to understand all you have written - and will follow any and all advices you give me!!
if you find anything that looks like the root cause i will be more than happy! 
i come here each day - sure thing!! Have a great day and all the best to you !!!
greetings zero

Answer (score 6, accepted):

run

```
$ sudo chmod -R 775 sites/default/files 
$ sudo chgrp -R www-data sites/default/files
```

from within the site root to assign all the files to the www-data group and give the group read and write permissions. You can also use CPanel to do this through the GUI, if that's your setup. This looks like a file permissions issue (and a very common one!).

Comment: +1 Remember to lock down `sites/default/settings.php` after running this

Comment: Hello dear Saun Dychko and Clive - many many thanks for the answers. I do not have CPanel - but i ask my serveradmin to  the changes accordingly. With FileZilla i cannot do the changes as adviced. But above all: i guess that we now have the root of all errors and issues - now we are very very close. Keep in touch - i keep you informed after the changes were made! Again - many thanks for your help so far!

Comment: hello clive and Shaun Dychko - thx  for the new input - see above the **very last / newest update** i will continue to work later the day. now i am in office.

Comment: a big step ahead - now i ve landed in the 
View activity_log_stream, displaying items of type Activity Log: <a href="http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/40/viewactivitylogstreamdi.jpg/">see the image:</a>  here i can change alot!  well but i guess that i have to figure out how...!?

Comment: see the update in the original posting above a  guy mentioned "I also had the same problem and it was solved by disabling CSS Optimizaition. checked all my CSS under /profiles/drupalcommons/themes, and all are UTF-8. Hi give this a try, you might find an answer http://drupal.org/node/445462 It seems to indicate I found the solution. You just have to convert all your css files in unix/utf8 and it's done. Hope it helps"   well see above more!

[end of the very very latest input to this topic]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the "permission" on the specified path?   e.g.  as "www-data" user, are you able to read the CSS folder?

UPDATED:

Thank Shaun Dychko for giving the detailed command.

Beside of making sure that you have 775(or 755) permissions on the target folder/files, you also have to make sure that you have the permission to access current folder and/or its parent folder "." and ".."

e.g.  if you are the admin and under a console, typing: 
( assuming "www-data" is a linux user, and "regular_user_group" is the group he belongs to. )

```
$ ls -al
drwxr------ 15 www-data regular_user_group 4096 2012-01-17 12:00 .
drwxr------ 15 www-data regular_user_group 4096 2012-01-17 12:00 ..
drwxrr-xr-x 15 www-data regular_user_group 4096 2012-01-17 12:00 app

# other files ...
```

see the line 2 and 3? In this case, although the "www-data" user have the access permission to the "app" folder, he is not able to access the "." and ".." folder. As a final result, the "app" folder is still not accessible.

So, please make sure that you have the permission both on the target file and the "." and ".." paths.

Comment: Btw - since the htaccess looks quite good [see the link in the thread ] i  guess that it's unlikely that we get HTML content when no css because of an .htaccess problem.

Guess that in the performance page, i have to try turning of css compression and java script compression. Also for images we need to make sure that the server has files placed correctly. Guess that we can track page-not-found errors if you have dblog module enabled, in admin reports.  I try to do so later the day and come back and give full report!  BTW - can we add a new theme!? Does this fit the errors -i do not belive this

Comment: I guess that the folder is in the **following path ..sites/default/files** - if it can imagine it right from the top of my head... **please correct me** if i am wrong - (i do not sit in front of  the machine with the installation...Well - i have found out that this folder does not contain any files... Well i am pretty sure that we are very very close to the solving of this issue! Love to hear form you !!

Comment: Siwei Shen - please please see the updated and corrected original-posting with more infos about the **foders and the users**  I guess that i am not able to read the css-folder. No - i am not since all of the below mentined folders are owned by the wwwrun-user. What doyou tink - maybe the issue is rooted in this circumstances°? Love to hear  from you! greetings zero

Comment: Siwei Sen thx alot. I guess that you are very close. Note I have such permission issues for a very loong time [on other installations. Well some of the issues may be rooted in the wwwrun-user-syndrome. This sometimes may cause some troubles - eg. on joomla-installations so far. So probably the occur here just another time. Siwei Sen i will check out all the advices and will look after the permissions later the day[i am in office right now] Then i come back and report all my findings. Well - Siwei - how do we proceed afterawards. can you suggest some fix!? [but wait i check the permits first]

Comment: Hi Zero, sorry for waiting, since I am not notified that you added comments. see my update. :)

Comment: hello dear Siewei Shen - thx  for the new input - see above the **very last / newest update** i will continue to work later the day. now i am in office.

Comment: Hello well i will check all the adjustmens tonight: i had some corrections and tests done last week accordingly some hints: "This is due that by install in the performance administrative section ( admin/settings/performance ) you have on Bandwidth optimizations the option "OPTIMIZE CSS FILES" and "OPTIMIZE JAVASCRIPT FILES" enabled. This settings are normally very usefully for production(live) sites-  i did this for testing and customize the Drupal Commons install cuz i thougth that it's better to disable as to have CSS and JS development support with tools like "Firebug" using Firefox."

Comment: a big step ahead - now i ve landed in the 
View activity_log_stream, displaying items of type Activity Log: <a href="http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/40/viewactivitylogstreamdi.jpg/">see the image:</a>  here i can change alot!  well but i guess that i have to figure out how...!?

Comment: see the update in the original posting above a  guy mentioned "I also had the same problem and it was solved by disabling CSS Optimizaition. checked all my CSS under /profiles/drupalcommons/themes, and all are UTF-8. Hi give this a try, you might find an answer http://drupal.org/node/445462 It seems to indicate I found the solution. You just have to convert all your css files in unix/utf8 and it's done. Hope it helps"   well see above more!

[end of the very very latest input to this topic]